# Getting Error while trying to install gazebo9 after installing ROS noetic in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ros, ubuntu-20.04, gazebo-simu

I have removed complete ROS and gazebo in Ubuntu 20.04 and tried to install it fresh, but I am facing the errors while installing gazebo9, below are the errors

```
lucky@Lucky1461:~$ sudo apt-get install gazebo9 libgazebo9-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gazebo9 : Depends: libgazebo9 (= 9.12.0+dfsg-1build2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: gazebo9-common (= 9.12.0+dfsg-1build2) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: gazebo9-plugin-base but it is not going to be installed
 libgazebo9-dev : Depends: libgazebo9 (= 9.12.0+dfsg-1build2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gazebo9-common (= 9.12.0+dfsg-1build2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gazebo9-plugin-base (= 9.12.0+dfsg-1build2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to get solution , but in web it says to remove the package which is causing the problem  by using the command
sudo apt-get remove

and I dont no which package to remove exactly and dont want to take a risk,so I came here for the solution

Comment: What version of ROS have you installed and how have you installed it? When installing ROS, you can select the ros-desktop-full (eg: ros-melodic-desktop-full) install and it will also install Gazebo with it. I don't understand why you need to install Gazebo separately?

Comment: I have installed ROS-noetic and followed the steps in ros website and yes i did install it full, I tried that cuz, when i was working on the gazebo i am having erros and so i thought i will just try to install it, even so if i have gazebo , i think it should not show as i am having broken packages right?

Comment: I think the core reason is that WSL has been upgraded to use Ubuntu 22.04. I am getting the same error and that is what 'lsb_release -a` is showing (on a new Windows installation). Noetic is only supported on 20.04